# format time of this query result

Tags: oracle

I'm using this query to get the difference between two dates in oracle
the result should display num of days, hours, minutes
I did it like that

```sql
select r.created_date, r.updated_date, (r.updated_date - r.created_date) time from orders r;
```

result like that:-

```
[created_date] 01/01/20 07:00:00.000000000 PM    
-------                    
[updated_date] 21/01/20 06:20:00.000000000 AM   
------
[time] +19 11:20:00.000000
```

how to format +19 11:20:00.000000 to represent num of days, hours, and min in a readable way?
ex: 19 days, 11 h, 20 min
how to set aliases name for time column?

thanks.

Comment: Probably just a matter of finding a nice format for the TO_CHAR function to transform the interval to a varchar2. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions200.htm#SQLRF06129

Comment: @LukStorms - unfortunately in Oracle that doesn't work - TO_CHAR applied to intervals does not honor format models.

Comment: Why is +19 11:20:00.000000 not "readable" already? It seems perfectly readable to me.

Comment: @mathguy Okay, I see. Just needs a work-around then. F.e. by adding the interval to a date.  F.e. `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('31-DEC-00')+(r.updated_date - r.created_date),'DD "days" HH24 "hours" MI "minutes"')`

Comment: @LukStorms That does not give the expected answer when there is more than a month between the two dates. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6c741c5c3843d9f992e7064a208c4c03)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of subtracting two timestamps is an interval data type, which you can't format directly.

You could extract each component individually, which to avoid repetition could be done in a CTE, e.g.:

```
with cte as (
  select r.created_date, r.updated_date, (r.updated_date - r.created_date) time
  from orders r
)
select cte.created_date,
  cte.updated_date,
  extract(day from cte.time) || ' days '
    || extract(hour from cte.time) || ' hours '
    || extract(minute from cte.time) || ' minutes'
    as time
from cte;
```

| CREATED_DATE | UPDATED_DATE | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-JAN-20 19.00.00.000000000 | 21-JAN-20 06.20.00.000000000 | 19 days 11 hours 20 minutes |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a77366453967b5a7a9244bae81c0dad8)

You've shown a simple examples, but you may want to include fractional minutes, or show the seconds or even milliseconds as separate parts of the text. I've included a couple of variations in the fiddle.

As @WernfriedDomscheit mentioned in a comment, if the interval is negative - which is unlikely when comparing created/updated like this, but still useful to know - all the extracted components are negative, as shown in [this modified db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=25224df12adcaec66c97e9fbfd0216a5).

You could also use case expressions to skip components that are zero, which could get messy.

Comment: It might be mentioned, when the INTERVAL is negative (i.e. created_date > updated_date) , then **every** component is returned as negative number.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - thanks, not sure I've ever come across that, so good to know.

Answer (score 2):

If your columns have `TIMESTAMP` data types then:

```sql
select created_date,
       updated_date,
       EXTRACT(DAY FROM updated_date - created_date) || ' days '
       || EXTRACT(HOUR FROM updated_date - created_date) || ' hours '
       || EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM updated_date - created_date) || ' minutes '
       || EXTRACT(SECOND FROM updated_date - created_date) || ' seconds'
         AS time
from   orders;
```

If your columns have `DATE` data types then use a similar method but you have to explicitly cast the difference to an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`:

```sql
select created_date,
       updated_date,
       EXTRACT(DAY FROM (updated_date - created_date) DAY TO SECOND) || ' days '
       || EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (updated_date - created_date) DAY TO SECOND) || ' hours '
       || EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (updated_date - created_date) DAY TO SECOND) || ' minutes '
       || EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (updated_date - created_date) DAY TO SECOND) || ' seconds'
         AS time
from   orders;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders (
  created_date TIMESTAMP,
  updated_date TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES (TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP-1), SYSTIMESTAMP);
```

Outputs:

> | CREATED_DATE | UPDATED_DATE | TIME |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021-10-30 00:00:00.000000 | 2021-10-31 16:37:08.952012 | 1 days 16 hours 37 minutes 8.952012 seconds |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=758ca3c345bde97fea5a393ef1828013)*