# Convert format of Time

Tags: sql, oracle

need to change the format of time difference

for eg :

I have a difference of 83.08 mins

DIFF (FORMAT)-  NEED TO BE 1 hour 23 mins

Need to convert the time diffrence by hours and mins

Comment: What data type are those values? If they are dates or timestamp and have non-zero second values then how do you want to treats partial minutes in the difference (floor/round)? What have you tried and what exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: Or a duplicate of [format time of this query result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69787181/1509264)